# Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers, community

Following up on this decision: [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers)

Stack Exchange will be altering the way accepted answers work. Accepted answers will no longer *have to be* pinned at the top. Instead, it is possible to rank the answers based purely on their score, with the accepted answer somewhere among them.

We, as a community, can decide if we want to have this new behaviour on our site or not. Be aware that this is a setting that is toggled for the *whole* site. No one can change this behaviour except for staff at Stack Exchange.

Please vote for one of the answers below to weigh in on the decision.

(You can also add in your own answer if you have any more questions or remarks.)

Comment: I can't vote for the answers I myself created, so I'm registering my vote here: *YES, unpin accepted answers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your patience in getting this change enacted here. I've changed the site setting for the main Graphic Design Stack Exchange site for you as of just now. If, at some point in the future, you want to go back to pinning accepted answers, please start a new meta discussion about it and flag it for our attention with the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag.

I've only changed this on the main site, not on meta as well – most sites have only wanted to change this on main. If you'd like to also unpin accepted answers on meta, please let us know.

Comment: Thank you V2Blast

Answer (score 5):

## YES, unpin accepted answers

Yes, we want the new behaviour where accepted answers are no longer pinned at the top, but rather sorted amongst the other answers based on their score.

Answer (score 2):

## NO, keep pinning accepted answers

No, we do not want the new behaviour. Keep pinning accepted answers to the top of the list, regardless of their score or the score of other answers.

Comment: It seems we will be unpinning the accepted answers. However, Glorfindel has written a user script that pins them back if you really want this behaviour back: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369579/297831